# How can I disable my checkbox from AngularJS input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, disabled-input, angularjs-ng-disabled

```
<div ng-repeat="x in spaceutilization">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{x.filenumber}}" id="{{x.id}}" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP{{x.initials}}.dwg" /><label for="{{x.id}}"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs"> PDF</button></label><br />
</div>
```

I need to be able to add something to this snippet that disables the input checkbox based on another AngularJS input such as {{x.status}}. I tried simply doing:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{x.filenumber}}" id="{{x.id}}" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP{{x.initials}}.dwg" {{x.status}} />
```

Where `status:'disabled'` but that gave an output of

```
{{x.status}}=""
```

within the input element...which I don't understand why at all. But it seemed like the simplest route.

Comment: You can't add attributes dynamically using Interpolation method to your html tag. In your case you can simply do `ng-disabled="x.status"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `ng-disabled="expression"` directive, on basic of expression evaluation value it add disabled attribute to that element.Also for better attribute values evaluation you could use `ng-attr` directive

**Markup**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-attr-name="{{x.filenumber}}" ng-attr-id="{{x.id}}" class ="pdffiles" 
value="101SP{{x.initials}}.dwg" ng-disabled="x.status == 'disabled'"/>
```

If `x.status` does return a `bool` value then you could directly used `ng-disabled="{{x.status}}"`

Comment: do you mean {{x.status}} == 'disabled' ?

Also, what would status equal? What if I don't what the checkbox disabled?

Comment: Using @Rahil Wazir's comment above, I did ng-disabled="{{x.status}}" where status:'true' or status:'false"

Comment: @Christine268  hey don't use interpolation with `ng-disabled` directive, `ng-disabled` directive is matured enough to evaluate scope variables, It must be `ng-disabled="x.status"` if `x.status` has boolean

Comment: @pankajparker when I change it to ng-disabled="x.status" it no longer works. status either equals true or false. ng-disabled="{{x.status}}" is what's working for me.

Comment: @Christine268 I updated answer, Now you can do upvote & accept it Thanks :)

Comment: idk I think I tried clicking it even though I had already upvoted it. My reputation when down from 15 so now I can't vote. Error in the way the web registers the vote.